# Decimals not displaying when using Float or Double type

Tags: c++, double, visual-c++

My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const float dollar = 1.00;

    cout << "You have " << dollar*10.00 << " dollars." << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner to C++. I typed this code just playing around and assumed that the console would display "You have 10.00 dollars, but it actually displays that I have "10" and not "10.00" dollars. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are dealing with dollar amounts, you can set the following before writing to `cout`:

```
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
```

[Live code example at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eae852c5c36d8c56)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    const float dollar = 1.00;
    std::cout.precision(2);
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
    cout << "You have " << dollar*10.00 << " dollars." << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great and works perfectly; however, I do not know how to change the precision later into the program. How could I do that if I no longer need the decimals to show?

Comment: Make a call to `std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::fixed)`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library already has some code to deal with monetary values. In C++98/03, it's sufficiently painful to use that it's probably not worth the trouble, but in C++11, a couple of I/O manipulators were added that make them quite easy to use.

In the default "C" locale, they probably won't be of much use, but in a nationalized locale, they will format money as you'd normally expect for that locale. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    long double amt;

    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));

    std::cin >> std::get_money(amt);
    std::cout << std::put_money(amt) << "\n";
}
```

This uses the `""` locale, which chooses a locale based on how the OS is configured. For example, in my case the OS is set up for US English, so that chooses the US English locale.

Based on the locale, this displays the money as (the programmers guess) money would normally be displayed in that locale. For example, if I enter "10" (with or without some 0's after the decimal point), it prints the value out as `10.00`.

If I prefer, I can specify a locale--for example, I can specify "de" to get a German locale. In this case, the value will (at least with the compiler I have handy) be printed out using German conventions (`.` as a thousands separator and `,` as a decimal separator). Also note that I can specify the locale for `std::cin` separately from the locale for `std::cout`, so I can (for example) set `cin` to US English, and `cout` to German. If I do so, I can enter `1,234,567.89` as the input, and receive `1.234.567,89` as the output. (Note that although it converts the formatting from US to German convention, it does not automatically convert my input in dollars to Euros at output).

Note that `put_money` also automatically restores the previous formatting after it does its thing. For example, if I change the last line above to: `std::cout << std::put_money(amt) << "\n";`, then enter `10` as the input, I get `10.00    10`.

Also note that (at least with VC++) `std::get_money` actually stores the value as an integer count of cents, which will prevent most rounding errors. So, if I enter `10` what's actually stored is `1000`, which is then re-scaled to display as `10.00` at output.

If you're stuck with an older compiler that doesn't include `std::get_money` and `std::put_money`, it's probably easiest to just copy their definitions from the standard, put them into a header of your own, and use them anyway. If you don't want to do that, I'd consider defining a `money` class that stores an amount of money, and overloads `operator>>` and (especially) `operator<<` to handle formatting as you see fit, so writing out a monetary value would be something like:

```
money m(10);

std::cout << m;
```

...and the `operator<<` would handle all the `std::setprecision` and such to display that with two places after the decimal point and such.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't format output, cout will cut unnecessary zeroes. You can set precision of output.

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<dollar<<endl;
```

Comment: Must I do this to every line individually? Or is there some sort of scope for this.

Answer (score 1):

//cout << setprecision(3) << fixed;

Also one more point: don’t put `using namespace std;` inside the *main* statement,

Add header `#include <iomanip>`

#### Code

```
int main()
{
    float dollar = 2.00f;


    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed;
    std::cout  << dollar << " dollars." << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```